# Execute Cypress client side command in order

Tags: cypress

just starting to learn Cypress and I’m trying to figure out the proper way of executing a non- UI actions such as run a sql command within a test in but having it run in the proper order.  I guess adding it to Cypress’s command stack.

Comment: You can do an `await` to wait for a POST request to be executed on the server - is that what you need?

Comment: I will be running powershell to perform the DB restore of a SQL .bak file

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense for Cypress to be waiting for a backup restore, because you really don't know how long it's going to take, and it may also fail.

I would think about using a service like Circle CI, Jenkins or similar, that will sequence operations (like the restore), regardless of how long it takes, and when that is complete, it can kick off the cypress script.